# Prevent multiple user enter by same username at the same time? symfony 1.4

Tags: symfony-1.4, multiple-users

How to prevent multiple users enter by same username at same time? Example: When username is using by me and other guys try to enter with my username at same time it should display error like "Your username is already in use". 
I tried saving username in DB that user using it already. But leaving account without logging off is being  problem  now.

Answer (score 0):

You would use sfValidatorDoctrineUnique.

http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/forms/1_4/en/B-Validators#chapter_b_sub_sfvalidatordoctrineunique

You should also make your database column unique as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this, inside the form's "configure" function :

```
$this->validatorSchema->setPostValidator(new sfValidatorDoctrineUnique(
                                            array('model' => 'sfGuardUser', 'column' => array('username')), 
                                            array('invalid' => 'Username already in use') )
                                        );
```

I'm assuming here that you're using the sfGuard plugin, else you'll have to modify the model. And as @Kevin said, the column must be unique